# Undo git pull from master, bring repo to state with local changes

Tags: git, github, merge, version-control

I have a git repo, on which I am making my changes, with multiple commits, which aren't merged yet.

I have multiple local changes which aren't commited, but I have added the files to the git.

I wanted to get changes from master so I did

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

Now, I realised I didn't have to do it pull and need to revert the pull from master to come to a state where my local will have only my committed/uncommitted changes.

This is how my git reflog looks :

```
git reflog
565eb (HEAD -> mainline) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD
565eb (HEAD -> mainline) HEAD@{1}: commit: <commit msg>
71edb HEAD@{2}: commit: <commit msg>
909ba HEAD@{3}: commit: <commit msg>
.
.
.
```

I am reading git reset --hard as an option but not sure if I will loose my uncommitted changes OR can I first commit and then do reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git reset --hard` will remove your uncommitted changes.

What I would do is to create another `git stash` to save my uncommitted changes.

Then to the `git reset --hard` to go back to the revision you want.

And then use `git stash pop` to get your uncommitted changes back.

If you want to be sure you do not lose anything you can make a backup copy of your folder before any change, so you have a saved state and can experiment freely.